# Printing a very large whole number in C

Tags: c

I've stored a very large number in a float variable, but when I print it I want to only display the whole number part and nothing after the decimal point.

For numbers in the int or long range, I would do a casting but this hasn't helped me because the number I want to print is too long for int or long.

I've looked at this explanation: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html but I haven't succeeded in solving this.

this is my code and my attempt to do the casting:

```
double sum=552074001368;
long long_sum;
long_sum = (long)(sum);      //int casting for double "add" 
if(sum>=0) printf("=\n%ld\n",long_sum);
else printf("=\n%ld\n",-long_sum);
```

I don't want to use a specific precision like `printf("%15f")` because this variable fluctuates and is sometimes very short like 4 digits.

Comment: What's wrong with the above code? It prints 552074001368. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @MikeKwan it'll only do that on systems with a 64-bit `long`.

Comment: The fundamental problem with casting is that it will only work if the target type (long, in this case) will hold the number -- in which case, you might as well just use that target type to start with.

Comment: @Mike i have a 64-bit system but it still prints -2147483648

Comment: @nofe: some 64-bit systems still have 32-bit long. You might try `long long` instead.

Comment: With 64 bit longs, you still run out of space with values over 20 digits. Best keep the double and just print that.

Comment: @MrLister: `double` is usually 64 bits as well, with only 53 devoted to significand, so you get only about 15 significant digits. `long double` is sometimes 80 bits, with a ~64-bit significand, to also get  ~20 significant digits (but in a fair number of cases, `long double` is also 64 bits/15 significant digits.

Comment: @JerryCoffin No, I didn't mean the precision, I meant that you'd get an overflow when converting to long. You can print a double in many more digits if you want (even if most of the digits wouldn't make sense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're after is `%.0f`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double x = 1234.567;

    printf("%.0f", x);
    return 0;
}
```

...prints:

```
1235
```

Comment: Your libc must be broken. On my system, that prints `1235`.

Comment: @larsmans: yeah -- was editing as you commented. If he needs truncation instead of rounding, your answer is right: he should also use `floor`.

Comment: @MrLister: most of the downvotes were given when your answer said `%g`, and most of the downvoters probably haven't looked at it again to see that you've changed it to use `%f`.

Comment: @MrLister: It happens sometimes -- for better or worse, the system tends to reward the first (or first few) reasonable answers. I've written a fair number of long, careful answers that got little or no rep, while a (IMO) comparatively mediocre one that was posted sooner got a lot. Such is life...

Answer (score 6):

Use the precision modifier `.0` and print the `floor` of the number:

```
printf("%.0f\n", floor(sum));
```

(Or the `floor` of the `abs`, if you want only the magnitude, as in your example code.)

Comment: this may be the right answer but i'm not allowed to use functions we haven't been taught in class, and I haven't seen floor() anywhere.

Comment: You don't need `floor` with that notation. See my earlier answer.

Comment: @nofe: Maybe just try without the `floor` then-- I think the precision modifier may do the job sufficiently. The only danger might be rounding up if the decimal is greater than `.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting to long at all?  Use the printf format specifiers to control what and how many characters are printed.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Remember that both the width and the precision can be specified by a variable and doesn't have to be known at compile time:

```
printf("=\n%.*lf\n", 4, sum); // print 4 places behind the decimal point

 int i;
 i = 5;
// print only the whole number part of sum and output at least i characters,
//    pad with leading spaces if number requires fewer than i characters 
printf("=\n%*.*lf\n", i, 0, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic:

```
double sum=552074001368;
```

Since that is an integer literal, the compiler will first check if the number will fit in an `int`, then `long`, then `long long`. If it won't fit in `long long` I suspect you'll get either a compiler error or undefined behavior wrap-around, I'm not sure of which.

If your compiler supports `long long`, then the code will work and the number will be stored in a temporary `long long` (which will be optimized away). This `long long` is then stored inside a `double`.

Instead, write like this:

```
double sum=552074001368.0;
```

The .0 syntax gives you a double floating point literal without involving integer types at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
double sum=552074001368LL;
long long long_sum;
long_sum = (long long)(sum);
if(sum>=0) printf("=\n%lld\n",long_sum);
else printf("=\n%lld\n",-long_sum);
```